# How to check if correct files are deleted using mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a program which makes a directory for each entry in a given list of countries. 
For example: if you pass a list of Albania, Portugal, Belgium, Israel it will create a directory ABC (where the directories Albania and Belgium are created), PQR (where the directory Portugal is created), GHI (where the directory Israel is created). If the program was run again with Botswana and Poland it will delete the directories ABC and PQR and then recreate them again.

I want to write a test that verifies that only the directories ABC and PQR are removed and the directory GHI remains. The program works OK, but now I need to write a mockito test and I have no idea how to do it. I'm new to mockito :/ Here are my classes.

```
public class FileDeleter implements Deleter {

    public void deleteDirectories(List<GroupOfCountries> organizedCountries, String path) {
        List<String> listOfThreeLettersGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GroupOfCountries groupedCountries : organizedCountries) {
            listOfThreeLettersGroups.add(groupedCountries.getName()); //Here it's adding "ABC" and "PQR" to ArrayList because my countries are Albania, Belgium and Portugal.
        }

        for (String directoryToDelete : listOfThreeLettersGroups) { 
            String pathOfGorupDirectory = (path + File.separator + directoryToDelete); //Here it's creating paths to ABC and PQR directories, for example /home/test/ABC
            File tempfile = createFile(pathOfGorupDirectory);
            deleteDirectory(tempfile);
        }
    }

    protected File createFile(String pathOfGorupDirectory) {
        return new File(pathOfGorupDirectory);
    }

    private boolean deleteDirectory(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] children = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDirectory(children[i]);
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

And here is my test. I tried to to this in that way, but I'm not sure what more I can do here :/

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FileDeleterTest {

    @Mock
    private File file;

    @Mock
    private File childFile;

    private FileDeleter fileDeleter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        fileDeleter = new FileDeleter(userInputs) {
            protected File createFile(String pathOfGorupDirectory) {
                return file;
            };
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultipleGroupsReplace() {

        File[] fileChildrenEmpty = new File[0];
        File[] fileChildrenWithMockChild = new File[] { childFile };
        doReturn(true).doReturn(false).when(file).isDirectory();
        doReturn(fileChildrenWithMockChild).doReturn(fileChildrenEmpty).when(file).listFiles();
        String path = "somepath";

        List<GroupOfCountries> groupOfCountries = new ArrayList<GroupOfCountries>();
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        countries.add(new Country("Albania"));
        countries.add(new Country("Belgium"));
        GroupOfCountries firstGroup = new GroupOfCountries("ABC", countries);
        groupOfCountries.add(firstGroup);

        countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        countries.add(new Country("Portugal"));
        GroupOfCountries secondGroup = new GroupOfCountries("PQR", countries);
        groupOfCountries.add(secondGroup);

        fileDeleter.deleteDirectories(groupOfCountries, path);

        verify(childFile, times(1)).delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Mockito for this test. Just use real file system

Comment: I have to use Mockito. I need to learn how to use it and I need to learn it on this example.

Comment: Is there for example any way to return dir.getName() from deleteDirectory method?

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have created your FileDeleter class it is very difficult to test. I would suggest that you move the file operations to a separate class/interface so that you can mock its bahavior using Mockito. You're classes could be come something like this.

```
public class CountryDirectoryDeleter {

    private Deleter fileDeleter;

    public CountryDirectoryDeleter() {
        fileDeleter = new FileDeleter();
    }

    public void deleteDirectories(List<GroupOfCountries> organizedCountries, String path) {
        List<String> listOfThreeLettersGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GroupOfCountries groupedCountries : organizedCountries) {
            listOfThreeLettersGroups.add(groupedCountries.getName()); //Here it's adding "ABC" and "PQR" to ArrayList because my countries are Albania, Belgium and Portugal.
        }

        for (String directoryToDelete : listOfThreeLettersGroups) {
            String pathOfGorupDirectory = (path + File.separator + directoryToDelete); //Here it's creating paths to ABC and PQR directories, for example /home/test/ABC
            File tempfile = fileDeleter.createFile(pathOfGorupDirectory);
            fileDeleter.deleteDirectory(tempfile);
        }
    }


    public FileDeleter getFileDeleter() {
        return fileDeleter;
    }

    public void setFileDeleter(FileDeleter fileDeleter) {
        this.fileDeleter = fileDeleter;
    }
}
```

The FileDeleter would look like this:

```
public class FileDeleter implements Deleter {

    public File createFile(String pathOfGorupDirectory) {
        return new File(pathOfGorupDirectory);
    }

    public boolean deleteDirectory(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] children = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDirectory(children[i]);
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Then in your test you can set the 'fileDeleter' field in the CountryDirectoryDeleter to be a mock object, and in your test you can verify that deleteDirectory() method of the mock object is invoked using the correct file names.

```
Mockito.verify(mockFileDeleter).when(deleteDirectory("directory name to verify"));
```